# Origin of Hadran

Tags: sources-mekorot, siyum

What is the origin of the *hadran*? I'm referring to the whole extended multi-paragraphed "prayer", not to the words "Hadran alach."

Comment: see the back of the Oz Vhedar where the hadran is it has a nice explanation

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful? http://seforim.blogspot.com/2011/05/hadaran-who-is-going-down-to-pit-of.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ספר האשכול in [Hilchos Sefer Torah 14](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31467&st=&pgnum=52) brings down the Hadran Alach, Yehi Ratzon, and sons of Rav Pappa parts.  I think that is the earliest source, and he does not have the Haarev, Modim, or second Yehi Ratzon.